# Websphere application server on aix not starting

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1

While tring to start websphere server it is throwing the error:
thread server startup:2'' (0000000a) has been active for 786590 milliseconds and may be hung.

How to resolve this WSVR0605W error?

Answer (score 1):

That error will always be displayed when a thread has been running for a certain time. It is not for certain that this actually indicates an error, it depends on what your applications do on your server. If you have an operation that runs within the same thread for more than 10 minutes, this error will eventually pop up even though it is within the normal operation of your application. If this is the case you will later get a message of the style `[10/29/13 8:23:11:008 CET] 00004709 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0606W: Thread "Thread_ID" (00004709) was previously reported to be hung but has completed.  It was active for approximately 727968 milliseconds.  There is/are 0 thread(s) in total in the server that still may be hung.`

If you do not have anything that should be running for that long, the thread may indeed be hung and you need to investigate what operation exactly is hung. Start by examining the logs using the same thread ID as the one reported as possibly hung.